# Is there a way to heat a precooked ham in a 425 degree oven?

Tags: oven, heat, ham

Is it possible to protect a precooked ham while heating in an over hot oven?

For example is it possible to heat a precooked while cooking a turkey at 425 by say wrapping it in a double layer of foil, or placing it in a pan of water, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

425° F is so hot that it will surely burn over-do the outside of a ham before the inside will get warm.  However, you can slice the ham then warm it for about 10 minutes.  Slicing it will allow the whole slice to get warm, while not over-cooking the outside.

Comment: I did end up slicing the ham and tossing it in the oven protected by heavy duty aluminum foil.  Though my two large pans ended up in there for longer, the overall result was well heated ham that was not overly dried out.